# Unresponsive actor system: ThreadPoolExecutor dispatcher only creates core thread pool, apparently ignores max thread pool size

Tags: java, multithreading, scala, akka, blocking

Update: I've found that my program remains responsive if I set the `ThreadPoolExecutor's` core pool size to be the same as the max pool size (29 threads).  However, if I set the core pool size to 11 and the max pool size to 29 then the actor system only ever creates 11 threads.  How can I configure the `ActorSystem` / `ThreadPoolExecutor` to continue to create threads to exceed the core thread count and stay within the max thread count?  I would prefer not to set the core thread count to the max thread count, as I only need the extra threads for a job cancellation (which should be a rare event).

---

I have a batch program running against an Oracle database, implemented using Java/Akka typed actors with the following actors:

1. `BatchManager` is in charge of talking to the REST controller.  It manages a `Queue` of uninitialized batch jobs; when an uninitialized batch job is polled from the queue then it is turned into a `JobManager` actor and executed.
2. `JobManager` maintains a queue of stored procedures and a pool of `Workers`; it initializes each `Worker` with a stored procedure, and when a `Worker` finishes it sends the procedure's result to the `JobManager`, and the `JobManager` sends another stored procedure to the `Worker`.  The batch terminates when the job queue is empty and all `Workers` are idle, at which point the `JobManager` reports its results to the `BatchManager`, shuts down its workers (via `TypedActor.context().stop()`), and then shuts itself down. The `JobManager` has a `Promise<Status> completion` that is completed when the job successfully finishes or else when the job is terminated due to cancellation or a fatal exception.
3. `Worker` executes a stored procedure.  It creates the [OracleConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleConnection.html) and a [CallableStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html) used to execute the stored procedures, and registers an `onFailure` callback with `JobManager.completion` to `abort` the connection and `cancel` the statement.  This callback doesn't use the actor system's execution context, instead it uses an execution context created from a cached executor service created in `BatchManager`.

My config is

```
{"akka" : { "actor" : { "default-dispatcher" : {
    "type" : "Dispatcher",
    "executor" : "default-executor",
    "throughput" : "1",
    "default-executor" : { "fallback" : "thread-pool-executor" }
    "thread-pool-executor" : {
        "keep-alive-time" : "60s",
        "core-pool-size-min" : coreActorCount,
        "core-pool-size-max" : coreActorCount,
        "max-pool-size-min" : maxActorCount,
        "max-pool-size-max" : maxActorCount,
        "task-queue-size" : "-1",
        "task-queue-type" : "linked",
        "allow-core-timeout" : "on"
}}}}}
```

The number of workers is configured elsewhere, currently `workerCount = 8`; `coreActorCount` is `workerCount + 3` while `maxActorCount` is `workerCount * 3 + 5`.  I'm testing this on a Macbook Pro 10 with two cores and 8GB of memory; the production server is considerably larger.  The database I'm talking to is behind an extremely slow VPN.  I'm running all of this using Oracle's JavaSE 1.8 JVM.  The local server is Tomcat 7.  The Oracle JDBC drivers are version 10.2 (I might be able to convince the powers that be to use a newer version).  All methods either return `void` or `Future<>` and ought to be non-blocking.

When one batch terminates successfully then there is no issue - the next batch starts immediately with a full complement of workers.  However, if I terminate the current batch via `JobManager#completion.tryFailure(new CancellationException("Batch cancelled"))` then the `onFailure` callbacks registered by the `Workers` fire off, and then the system becomes unresponsive. Debug printlns indicate that the new batch starts with three out of eight functioning workers, and the `BatchManager` becomes completely unresponsive (I added a `Future<String> ping` command that just returns a `Futures.successful("ping")` and this also times out).  The `onFailure` callbacks are executing on a separate thread pool, and even if they were on the actor system's thread pool I should have a high enough `max-pool-size` to accommodate the original `JobManager`, its `Workers`, its `onFailure` callbacks, and a second `JobManager` and is `Workers`.  Instead I seem to be accommodating the original `JobManager` and its `Workers`, the new `JobManager` and less than half of its `Workers`, and nothing left over for the `BatchManager.`  The computer I'm running this on is short on resources, but it seems like it ought to be able to run more than a dozen threads.

Is this a configuration issue?  Is this due to a JVM-imposed limit and/or a Tomcat-imposed limit?  Is this due to a problem with how I'm handling blocking IO?  There are probably several other things I could be doing wrong, these are just what came to mind.

[Gist of CancellableStatement](https://gist.github.com/kcleereman/48d3bfaa4a6599160867) where the `CallableStatement` and `OracleConnection` are cancelled

[Gist of Immutable](https://gist.github.com/kcleereman/f8f11d010f88df5b36ce) where `CancellableStatements` are created

[Gist of JobManager's cleanup code](https://gist.github.com/kcleereman/d729d47d80262961f1a6)

[Config dump](https://gist.github.com/kcleereman/ee28474af7b4bc2c1f9e) obtained via `System.out.println(mergedConfig.toString());`

---

Edit: I believe that I've narrowed down the problem to the actor system (either its configuration or its interaction with blocking database calls).  I eliminated the `Worker` actors and moved their workload to `Runnables` that execute on a fixed-size `ThreadPoolExecutor`, where each `JobManager` creates its own `ThreadPoolExecutor` and shuts it down when the batch completes (`shutDown` on normal termination, `shutDownNow` on exceptional termination).  Cancellation runs on a cached thread pool instantiated in the `BatchManager`.  The actor system's dispatcher is still a `ThreadPoolExecutor` but with only a half dozen threads allocated to it.  Using this alternate setup, cancellation executes as expected - the workers terminate when their database connections are aborted, and the new `JobManager` executes immediately with a full complement of worker threads.  This indicates to me that this is not a hardware/JVM/Tomcat issue.

---

Update: I did a thread dump using [Eclipse's Memory Analyzer](https://eclipse.org/mat/).  I discovered that the cancellation threads were hanging on `CallableStatement.close()`, so I reordered the cancellation so that `OracleConnection.abort()` preceded `CallableStatement.cancel()` and this cleared up the problem - the cancellations all (apparently) executed correctly.  The `Worker` threads continued to hang on their statements, though - I suspect that my VPN may be partially or totally to blame for this.

```
PerformanceAsync-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-19
  at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;[BIII)I (Native Method)
  at java.net.SocketInputStream.read([BIII)I (SocketInputStream.java:150)
  at java.net.SocketInputStream.read([BII)I (SocketInputStream.java:121)
  at oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive()V (Unknown Source)
  at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.receive()V (Unknown Source)
  at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket()V (Unknown Source)
  at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read([BII)I (Unknown Source)
  at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read([B)I (Unknown Source)
  at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read()I (Unknown Source)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1()S (T4CMAREngine.java:1109)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalSB1()B (T4CMAREngine.java:1080)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive()V (T4C8Oall.java:485)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(ZZZZ)V (T4CCallableStatement.java:218)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeForRows(Z)V (T4CCallableStatement.java:971)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout()V (OracleStatement.java:1192)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal()I (OraclePreparedStatement.java:3415)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute()Z (OraclePreparedStatement.java:3521)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.execute()Z (OracleCallableStatement.java:4612)
  at com.util.CPProcExecutor.execute(Loracle/jdbc/OracleConnection;Ljava/sql/CallableStatement;Lcom/controller/BaseJobRequest;)V (CPProcExecutor.java:57)
```

However, even after fixing the cancellation order I still have the problem where the actor system isn't creating enough threads: I'm still only getting three out of eight workers in the new batch, with new workers being added as the cancelled workers have their network connections time out. In total I've got 11 threads - my core pool size, out of 29 threads - my max pool size.  Apparently the actor system is ignoring my max pool size parameter, or I'm not configuring the max pool size correctly.

Comment: Are you creating new connection every time in worker thread Or are you using getConnection() from your ConnectionPool? If you are creating new Connection in Worker thread, please make sure that that connection is getting released properly. If you are getting the issue even with ConnectionPool from worker thread, we have to approach the problem differently

Comment: @sunrise76 I'm creating a new connection each time using a try-with-resources block to ensure that it's being closed

Comment: Creating and Closing connection is VERY expensive. Please get rid of it and Use Connection pool  with getConnection() & releaseConnection(). releaseConnection will release connection to the pool without close(), This model will scale for high traffic. And one more thing  - Get thread dump of your application and look out for "waiting for monitor entry" & "RUNNABLE" & "deadlock" statements

Comment: @sunrise76 Spring is taking care of caching connections behind the scenes, so `close` will either return the connection to the pool or else close the connection depending on Spring's (i.e. whether the core connection pool has been exceeded).  I'll dig around to see if I can dump the actor system's thread/actor state - it proxies the bejeesus out of everything and so it's difficult to get at its raw ExecutorService.

Comment: Did you get any clues from dump? Is Your server running in Linux?

Comment: @sunrise76 I haven't found a way to dump the state of Akka's [ActorSystem](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.0/akka/actor/ActorSystem.html), which is wrapping the primary `ThreadPoolExecutor` - the only visible interface is to a scala [ExecutionContext](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext) wrapper which doesn't tell me anything (and isn't serializable so I can't cheat).  The workaround code should be tested + checked in by this afternoon (GMT-6) at which point I'll wrestle with the `ActorSystem` some more.

Comment: If you are using Linux,  kill -SIGQUIT your_process_id will get the dump.

Comment: @sunrise76 I did a memory dump using Eclipse's memory analyzer; the problem seems to be that the actor system is only creating 11 threads (the core thread count for the `ThreadPoolExecutor`), and is ignoring the max thread count of 29.  If I set the core thread count to 29 then the problem goes away (or at least is masked), but I would prefer not to have to allocate that many threads for a rare cancellation event

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I don't know Akka)

By your below configuration of queue-size=-1, I guess, the task queue is unbounded.

```
  "task-queue-size": "-1",
  "task-queue-type": "linked"
```

[ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) will not spawn beyond core pool size unless the work queue is full and is not able to queue. Only if the task queue is full, it will start spawning upto max threads.

> If fewer than corePoolSize threads are running, the Executor always
>   prefers adding a new thread rather than queuing. If corePoolSize or
>   more threads are running, the Executor always prefers queuing a
>   request rather than adding a new thread. If a request cannot be
>   queued, a new thread is created unless this would exceed
>   maximumPoolSize, in which case, the task will be rejected.

Please check if you can fix up a limited queue size and see if the threads are increasing to max threads. Thanks.

Comment: Bingo, setting the queue size to 1 fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough code to provide a solution, but when system becomes unresponsive you can check your system resource utilitzation (cpu, ram) if they are not altered, check Oracle database.

If when you kill a group of connections anoter job starts immediately: I guess there are blocking sessions at oracle level (a not commited write-transaction is blocking another write transactions on the same resources).

When in unresponsive state, check blocking sessions:

```
SELECT s1.username || '@' || s1.machine
    || ' ( SID=' || s1.sid || ' )  is blocking '
    || s2.username || '@' || s2.machine || ' ( SID=' || s2.sid || ' ) ' AS blocking_status
    FROM v$lock l1, v$session s1, v$lock l2, v$session s2
    WHERE s1.sid=l1.sid AND s2.sid=l2.sid
    AND l1.BLOCK=1 AND l2.request > 0
    AND l1.id1 = l2.id1
    AND l1.id2 = l2.id2
```